# Display MySQL Data in Recycleview using fragments

Tags: android

I want to display my data inside a fragment but it seems like some methods are not applicable in fragments only in Activity. The text with * are causing me errors. How i can execute it on a fragment?

```
String urlAddress = "http://capstonproject.xyz/project/tourist/retrieve/adventure";
RecyclerView recyclerView;

public Fadventure() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    //RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fadventure, container, false);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fadventure, container, false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.adventure_list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(***this***));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    new DBFetch(***Fadventure.this***,recyclerView).execute();



    //return recyclerView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `this` try with `getActivity().getApplication()`.

hope it helps.

Comment: thanks. there are no errors anymore but no items displayed on my recycleview

Comment: try `getApplicationContext()` instead of `Fadventure.this`.

Comment: Is the `Fadventure.this` your current context, in which you're using `fragment`?

Comment: yes. thanks for the help! i just change it to Fadventure.this.getContext() to get the context of the fragment.